# How to look at files in a directory in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm writing a shell script that needs to print various data about the files and subdirectories in a directory. I start out by entering in the name of my directory like this. name=$1 so i'm just wondering how i would look in the directory and use the files and such inside it. Like how do i reference file1.txt and file2.txt etc.?

Comment: Please be more specific. What are you trying to do? Reference the files how? Echo the names, display the contents, what?

Comment: I just have to print the total number of files that are readable, writable and executable. I'm planning on creating a loop that checks each file separately.

Comment: Does it matter who can execute the file?  Suppose I have a file with permissions 241 (writable by owner, readable by group, executable by others).  Does that get counted as executable (I can't execute it, but others can)? It sounds like a job for `find`, where you don't have to reference the files by name because `find` determines the name and does most of the hard work.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have the directory you are interested in in $name then to get the files just do

```
files=`ls $name`
```

then for example you could to some thing like this

```
   files=`ls $name`
    for file in $files
    do
    if [ -r $name/$file ]
    then
    echo "$file is readable"
    fi
    done
```

Comment: Does this just print the names of the files and directories inside name, how can I check if each file is r, w, or x i tried                 if [ -r $file ]
then
  echo "$file is readable"
fi                  and it didn't work

Comment: if this truly did answer your question, feel free to accepted it as the answer and/or up vote.

Comment: Parsing `ls` output, esp. in a `for` loop, is a bad idea - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29. Use _pathname expansion_ instead: `for file in "$name"/* ...`. You should double-quote the variable references inside `[ ... ]` so that parsing doesn't break with filenames with embedded spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` and `wc` command(s) to do that,

```
# As an example,
find "$name" -perm -u=rwx | wc -l
```

Comment: How would I use the first file in the directory in an if statement, like if my directory is called Foo and i have a file in the directory called File but I don't know what the file name is. Sorry if my question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Test what in an `if` statement, this find command already checks for "rwx" permissions.

Comment: Well i have to print a separate sentence for each type like one for readable, one for writable, and one for executable, and it should be able to check if subdirectories are rwx as well.

Comment: You **really** should have included that in your question!

Comment: You probably mean `-perm -u=rwx` - without the `-`, the permissions matching is exact; i.e., only files where the group and others have NONE of these permissions would be returned; I also suggest double-quoting `$name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} +
```

Or

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs cat
```

see [xargs](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/xargs-examples/).